# Reset Accounts on an old Computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-server-2003

I’m interning at a small software company and trying to set up a local server. I’ve found two old machines that are available for use, running `Windows XP` and `Windows Server 2003`.

However, no one knows the passwords for these machines. Is there any way to reset the user accounts without any OS installation discs?

Answer (score 2):

There is a handy tool that will let you change the administrator (and any other user) passwords from a simple boot disk.  It's not the most friendly of utilities, but it does the job quite well.

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/